# How to read a file from USB Device using Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, osx-snow-leopard

I am very new to Mac OS X development. I am implementing a USB based application. In my application When my USB device is connected to the system I need to read a file from USB and upload it to a web server.

I go through Google and some documents but I didn't get any information on this. Can you guys please suggest a best document or sample code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best places where to start are

[USB Device Interface Guide](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/index.html&ei=8NVtTpToGurz0gG8wvCeDg&usg=AFQjCNGszD5-RN5yNiBcAUBZxQYKT7qzUA&sig2=UaOQzngG9Td_Cw_ZLaW75g)
[Networking & Internet Starting Point](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html%2523//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301&ei=X9ZtTvHTKuP10gH2ofD2BA&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=I5nvk3gtOXZH0gvujdigpQ)

There you can also find links for further information and sample projects