# equivalent of /dev/input on OSX

Tags: macos, input, usb

I'm looking at tutorials no how to read from the playstation sixaxis controller over usb and it seems the in general you should look for a file object in `/dev/input`. I'm developing on OSX and this directory doesn't seem to exist and i cant fine any information on an equivalent. Does OSX have a similar mechanism for reading from usb devices?

Comment: Does this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385910/how-to-read-a-file-from-usb-device-using-mac-os-x

Comment: Also try searching SO for `[osx] [usb]`, see if any of those questions help.

Comment: hm.. just found this question - as it is exactly what i need too - e.g. differentiate two usb-keyboards  in OS X (in Linux as `/dev/input/...`). Wondering - do you found some solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a Human Interface Device (HID) on macOS.  For more details on how to access HID data on macOS, begin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405248/8258079